# Convert "Month `YY" string format to date in Bigquery standard SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have dates in the database in the following format stored as strings "April `20". I need to convert them to dates as I need to perform some calcualtioin (i.e. +12 month to a certain date). I tried **CAST date as DATE** but that does work and I see why. **PARSE_DATE** didn't work either. Yet not sure what could work. Hope someones has suggestions, much appreciated!

Comment: That's a terrible format. I would first try going to the source and see if they can pass a standard date format. How would you know that `'20` is 2020 or 1920?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it was the **PARSE_DATE** function. And the solution in this case is

```
Parse_DATE('%B `%y', date)
```